# Анимация DialogFragment на Android 5 работает нестабильно

Tags: java, android, анимация, dialogfragment

Есть готовое приложение. При тестировании выяснилось, что на пятых андроидах диалог в 2-3 случаев из 20 появляется без анимации с какими-то подергиваниями после появления (т.е. окно появляется без анимации, чуть-чуть буквально на пиксели расширяется и после этого видно как фон плавно затемняется). В остальных случаях анимация (пробовал и android.R.style.Animation_Dialog и свою кастомную) корректно отрабатывается. На более младших версиях все нормально - такого эффекта не наблюдается. Проверялось на разных мобильниках и эмуляторах.

Вот так вызывается диалог из Activity:

```
if (isActive) AuthDialog.makeDialog(context, this, null).show(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Вот хелпер для более удобного вызова диалога:

```
public class AuthDialog {
    AuthDialogFragment rDialog;

    public AuthDialog(Context context, DialogResultInterface listener, JSONObject content) {
        try {
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            rDialog = new AuthDialogFragment();
            rDialog.setResultListener(listener);
            arguments.putString(AuthDialogFragment.BUNDLE_CONTENT, content != null ? content.toString() : "{}");
            rDialog.setArguments(arguments);
            rDialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.Exception(e);
        }
    }

    public static AuthDialog makeDialog(Context context) {
        return new AuthDialog(context, null, null);
    }

    public static AuthDialog makeDialog(Context context, DialogResultInterface listener) {
        return new AuthDialog(context, listener, null);
    }

    public static AuthDialog makeDialog(Context context, DialogResultInterface listener, JSONObject content) {
        return new AuthDialog(context, listener, content);
    }

    public void show(Activity activity, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        rDialog.show(fragmentManager, "AuthDialog");
    }
}
```

Вот собственно сам класс диалога (пробовал как стандартный DialogFragment так и support версию):

```
public class AuthDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String BUNDLE_CONTENT = "bundle_parameters";
    private DialogResultInterface resultInterface;
    private JSONObject parameters = null;

    @Override
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
        super.setArguments(args);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().containsKey(BUNDLE_CONTENT)) {
            try {
                String strParam = getArguments().getString(BUNDLE_CONTENT);
                parameters = new JSONObject(strParam);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.Exception(e);
            }
        } else {
            parameters = new JSONObject();
        }

        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Logger.Log("Creating AuthDialog");
        View currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_login, container, false);

        try {
            Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
            window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = window.getAttributes();
            windowParams.dimAmount = 0.20f;
            windowParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
            windowParams.windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Dialog;
            window.setAttributes(windowParams);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.Exception(e);
        }

        currentView.findViewById(R.id.have_account).setOnClickListener(this);
        currentView.findViewById(R.id.new_user).setOnClickListener(this);
        currentView.findViewById(R.id.close_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        return currentView;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
    @Override
    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
            super.show(manager, tag);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View lv) {
        switch (lv.getId()) {
            case R.id.have_account:
                Logger.Log("User selected LOGIN button...");
                ......
                dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.new_user:
                Logger.Log("User selected REGISTER button...");
                ......
                dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.close_button:
                Logger.Log("User selected CLOSE button");
                dismiss();
                break;
            default:
                Logger.Log("Unknown click from " + lv.toString());
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setResultListener(DialogResultInterface listener) {
        if (listener != null) resultInterface = listener;
    }
}
```

Кто-нибуть сталкивался с таким поведением ? Это у меня ошибка или это известная проблема Android 5.1 ? Как это можно поправить ?

Comment: А вы не пробовали задавать анимацию и другие параметры окна через тему а не код?

Comment: Анимацию пробовал, а другие параметры это какие ?

Comment: Другие это весь этот код: `Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
            window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = window.getAttributes();
            windowParams.dimAmount = 0.20f;
            windowParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
            windowParams.windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Dialog;
            window.setAttributes(windowParams);`. Всё это можно и как мне кажется нужно задавать в теме.

Comment: Постараюсь проверить в ближайшие пару дней

Comment: Нет, перенос этого кода в стили не помог. Абсолютно ничего не изменилось. В логах тоже ничего подозрительного.... Отключение аппаратного ускорения в манифесте тоже не помогло.